# Show that $\mathbb{R} ^ {\mathbb{R}} = M \oplus L.$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $L = \{ f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} : f(-t) = f(t) \} $ and $M = \{ f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} : f(-t) = -f(t) \}$. Show that $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} = M \oplus L.$

I am having trouble with this. It is easy to show that $ M \cap L $ equals null vector. The problem starts when I have to prove that each function in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ can be written as sum of some function in $M$ and $L$. 
First function that came to my mind was constant funtion. How can I write it as sum of even and odd function?

Comment: Try $\frac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}$.  This is an even function.  Is the difference between this and $f$ odd?

Comment: For a constant function, $c=c+0$.

Comment: We have $$f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments suggest simple formulas, but suppose no formulas came to your mind and you wanted to somehow "brute force" this problem.

Consider an arbitrary $f \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$. For each $t$, consider $f(t)=A$ and $f(-t)=B$. Let's write down everything that we need to be true:
\begin{align*}
L(t) + M(t) &= A \\
L(-t) + M(-t) &= B \\
L(t) - L(-t) &= 0 \\
M(t) + M(-t) &= 0
\end{align*}
Let's suppose for the moment that $t \ne 0$, and so we can think of $L(t)$, $M(t)$, $L(-t)$, and $M(-t)$ as four independent unknown quantities that we need to solve for. So this is a system four linear equations in four unknowns, and we can solve it.

The case $t=0$ is a special case, we must have $M(0)=0$ and we can just take $L(0)=f(0)$.

Answer (score 3):

For

$f(t) \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \tag 1$

define

$f_+(t) = \dfrac{f(t) + f(-t)}{2}, \tag 2$

and

$f_-(t) = \dfrac{f(t) - f(-t)}{2}; \tag 3$

then

$f_+(-t) = \dfrac{f(-t) + f(-(-t))}{2} =  \dfrac{f(t) + f(-t)}{2} = f_+(t) \tag 4$

and

$f_-(-t) = \dfrac{f(-t) - f(-(-t))}{2} = \dfrac{f(-t) - f(t)}{2} = -f_-(t); \tag 5$

evidently

$f_+(t) \in L \tag 6$

and

$f_-(t) \in M; \tag 7$

also, it is easy to see that

$f(t) = f_+(t) + f_-(t); \tag 8$

thus

$\Bbb R^{\Bbb R} = L + M; \tag 9$

now if

$g(t) \in L \cap M, \tag{10}$

we have

$g(t) = g(-t) \tag{11}$

and

$g(-t) = -g(-t); \tag{12}$

these two together yield

$g(t) = -g(t) \Longrightarrow g(t) = 0; \tag{13}$

thus

$L \cap M = \{0\}, \tag{14}$

and thus we may write

$\Bbb R^{\Bbb R} = L \oplus M. \tag{15}$

Note the non-zero constant functions are all in $L$; the only constant in $M$ is $0$.